# Python PIL | RGB values are wrong

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, steganography

I am making a steganography program. I got it to work without PIL but it only works with bitmaps, so I did some research and I found and learned general PIL. I converted my algorithm to be compatible with PIL and it looks like it works, but when I go to decode it seems like it pulls numbers out of nowhere. After some debugging I believe there to be a pattern of sorts because it is only a few values off.

To further debug I've created a similar program that makes the image completely red, then reopens it and reads its pixel values, however, I seem to be encountering the same error. The weird thing is that my computer science teacher, who uses Python 2, isn't encountering this error. I was wondering if any more experienced PIL users know why this is and any fixes. I am using Python 3 on Windows 10.

Here is my code (This is the program I made for debugging):

```
from PIL import Image

def redify(file_name): #Function that turns the whole image red
    image = Image.open(file_name)
    image = image.convert("RGB")
    pixels = list(image.getdata())

    fileTypeIndex = 0
    for i in range(0,len(file_name)):
        if file_name[-i] == ".":
            fileTypeIndex = i
            break

    for x in range(0,len(pixels)):
        pixels[x] = 255,0,0

    final = Image.new(image.mode,image.size)
    final.putdata(pixels)
    final.save(file_name[:-fileTypeIndex] + "_redified" + file_name[-fileTypeIndex:])

def readImage(file_name): #Fucntion that opens an image and reads its data
    image = Image.open(file_name)
    image = image.convert("RGB")
    rgbList = list(image.getdata())
    print(rgbList) # This returns every pixel as (254,0,0)
                   # When I set each pixel to 0,255,0 it returns (0,255,1)
                   # When I set each pixel to 0,0,255 it returns (0,0,254)
                   # All of these shouldn't be occuring


redify("moon.jpg")
readImage("moon_redified.jpg")
```

Comment: You save the image to jpeg, which uses lossy compression and may alter some pixels a little bit. Bmp and png formats are lossless.

Comment: You know, it's a question that comes up fairly frequently in the topic of steganography and I keep telling myself one day I'll choose a canonical question to refer to for duplicates. :D But most questions are worded as "why doesn't my code work", which is legitimately puzzling as their code is correct. And if someone ever had the insight to wonder "why does jpeg alter my pixels", they're one google search away from finding the reason and hence not ask it here.

Comment: if you want to be tolerant to this a good search term is "forward error correction"